# WPF DataGridTextColumn and Tag

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn, datagridtextcolumn

I have a datagrid with several DataGridTextColumn defined.

I need to use the Textblock's Tag property. I can't find it on a DataGridTextColumn.

I found a workaround which works, i.e a DataTemplateColumn in which I declare the textblock, in which case I have access to the Tag property:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column with Tag accessible">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Tag="{Binding Variable1Name}"
                       Text="{Binding Variable2Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

It would be great however if I could achieve the same result with the DataGridTextColumn. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would be great however if I could achieve the same result with the `DataGridTextColumn`.

You can't since the `DataGridTextColumn` has no `Tag` property that you can set.

It's unclear why you need to set the `Tag` property at all but if you don't want to create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and a `CellTemplate` for each column, you could create a custom `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
public class CustomDataGridTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{ 
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem) 
    { 
        FrameworkElement fe = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
        if (fe is TextBlock textBlock)
        { 
            textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TagProperty, new Binding(TagPropertyName));  //use TagProperty here
        }
        return fe;
    }

    public string TagPropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you simply replace the built-in `DataGridTextColumn` with this one in your XAML:

```
<local:CustomDataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Variable2Name}" TagPropertyName="Variable1Name" />
```

Comment: wondering can we do the `Tag` for `DataGridTextColumn` using `CellStyle` ? 
<DataGridTextColumn >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Tag" Value="hello"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

Comment: @AbinMathew: No. A style with a `TargetType` of `DataGridCell` cannot set the property of a `TextBlock`. But please ask a question if you have one.